# Pdf file gets overwritten

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I am trying to write the byte array to a single PDF file. I want to write multiple byte arrays to a single file. I am using the below code.

```
foreach (string byteArray in byteArrayS)
{
  byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(byteArray);
  if (!File.Exists("filepath"))
  {
     File.WriteAllBytes("filepath", bytes);
  }
  else
  {                        
    using (FileStream stream = File.Open("filepath", FileMode.Append))
      {
         stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
      }
  }                        
 }
```

But While using the above code the file gets overwritten. Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your filepath is same everytime?

Comment: Yes. I want to write in the same file

Comment: I don't see any issue in the code you posted, I think you will need to give more hint to us. However I can see that you don't really need File.WriteAllBytes("filepath", bytes) this call. The FileStream call already does create or append action.

Comment: I have removed the  File.WriteAllBytes("filepath", bytes) and simplpy uses filestream still able to see only the first content. But if I open the same file in adobe reader, I am able to see the second content. I was not able to understand why it is behaving like this.